# How to stop a while loop processing integers with a string

Tags: python, list

I'm processing integer inputs from a user and would like for the user to signal that they are done with inputs by typing in 'q' to show they are completed with their inputs.

Here's my code so far:
(Still very much a beginner so don't flame me too much)

```
def main():
    print("Please enter some numbers. Type 'q' to quit.")
    count = 0
    total = 0
    num=[]
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    while num != "q":
        num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        count += 1
        total += num
    del record[-1]
    print (num)
    print("The average of the numbers is", total / count)
main()
```

Any feedback is helpful!

Comment: Take a look at https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/#the-python-break-and-continue-statements

Answer (score 1):

You probably get a `ValueError` when you run that code. That's python's way of telling you that you've fed a value into a function that can't handle that type of value.

Check the [Exceptions docs for more details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError).

In this case, you're trying to feed the letter "q" into a function that is expecting `int()` on line 6. Think of `int()` as a machine that only handles integers. You just tried to stick a letter into a machine that's not equipped to handle letters and instead of bursting into flames, it's rejecting your input and putting on the breaks.

You'll probably want to wrap your conversion from `str` to `int` in a [`try:` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to handle the exception.

```
def main():
    num = None
    while num != "q":
        num = input("Enter number: ")

        # try handles exceptions and does something with them
        try:
            num = int(num)
        # if an exception of "ValueError" happens, print out a warning and keep going
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f'that was not a number: {e}')
            pass
        
        # if num looks like an integer
        if isinstance (num, (int, float)):
            print('got a number')
```

Test:

```
Enter number: 1
got a number
Enter number: 2
got a number
Enter number: alligator
that was not a number: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'alligator'
Enter number: -10
got a number
Enter number: 45
got a number
Enter number: 6.0222
that was not a number: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6.0222'
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out why 6.02222 "was not a number."

Answer (score 0):

changing your code as little as possible, you should have...

```
def main():
    print("Please enter some numbers. Type 'q' to quit.")
    count = 0
    total = 0
    num=[]
    num.append(input("Enter a number: "))
    while num[-1] != "q":
        num.append(input("Enter a number: "))
        count += 1
        try:
            total += int(num[-1])
        except ValueError as e:
            print('input not an integer')
            break
    print (num)
    print("The average of the numbers is", total / count)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may attempt it the way:

```
def main():
    num_list = [] #list for holding in user inputs
    while True:
        my_num = input("Please enter some numbers. Type 'q' to quit.")
        if my_num != 'q':
            num_list.append(int(my_num)) #add user input as integer to holding list as long as it is not 'q'
        else: #if user enters 'q'
            print(f'The Average of {num_list} is {sum(num_list)/len(num_list)}') #calculate the average of entered numbers by divide the sum of all list elements by the length of list and display the result
            break #terminate loop
main()
```